# Viewcontroller shows before the animation get finished

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying animate and get transferred only when the animation gets finished..but everything works fine except the segue...when I clicked the button it navigates to another page...before the animation gets finished...  I a new bee to ios please mention my mistake...

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Lottie/lottie.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property UIView * AnimatedViewForLoading;
@property LOTAnimationView * LottieAnimationHourGlass;
@end


  -(IBAction)ButtonTouched:(id)sender {
     self.AnimatedViewForLoading = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(118, 318, 200, 150)];

[self.AnimatedViewForLoading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
// self.AnimatedViewForLoading.alpha = 0.0f;
//AnimatedViewForLoading.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;

self.LottieAnimationHourGlass = [LOTAnimationView animationNamed:@"hourglass"];
self.LottieAnimationHourGlass.frame = CGRectMake(118, 318, 200, 150);


// if(!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()){
// self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *blureffectview = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blurEffect];
blureffectview.frame = self.view.bounds;
blureffectview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:blureffectview];
[self.view insertSubview:_AnimatedViewForLoading aboveSubview:blureffectview];
//[self.view sendSubviewToBack:_AnimatedViewForLoading];
[self.view insertSubview:_LottieAnimationHourGlass aboveSubview:_AnimatedViewForLoading];
[_LottieAnimationHourGlass play];
_LottieAnimationHourGlass.loopAnimation = YES;

// }else{
//self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
// }

self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 delay:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    NSLog(@"oopssssss..........");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
        self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    }];
    if (finished == true) {

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourTimeisLoading" sender:_AnimatedViewForLoading];

    }




}];
//[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: the 2 scenarios we need to check

Comment: What are they @Anbu.karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scenario 1:

check your second completion

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 delay:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

NSLog(@"oopssssss..........");

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
    self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourTimeisLoading" sender:_AnimatedViewForLoading];

}];

}];
```

scenario 2:

ensure once your `performSegueWithIdentifier` is connected with VC not directed in button.If its directly connected with your UIButton,it won't consider anything inside the action handler.

Comment: Found my mistake now...@Anbu.karthik

Comment: @Rathna- what was the mistake you found

Comment: They connected the Vc with button that's why it showed before the animation gets finished @Anbu.karthik

Comment: Shall I ask you a question? How can I add an animated launch screen in ios

Comment: @Rathna - its the tricky way, its better can you call me, plz get my mob no in my profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174694/discussion-between-rathna-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Is there any way to push custom notification in APNS @Anbu.karthik